# renv - manually overwrite package version in lock file

Tags: r, renv

I cannot fully restore one package in `renv` lock file, but I am able to install different version of this package. So I wonder if I can manually overwrite package version in lock file. Do I just need to replace version number? Should I change hash as well? What are the consequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can -- `renv.lock` is just JSON, so you can modify it as needed if you need to tweak a particular entry. (Or, you can use `renv::record(<package>@<version>)` to explicitly update the lockfile using `renv` APIs.)

If you're changing entries in `renv.lock`, you should normally remove the Hash component for modified entries. The hash is used for caching; it allows `renv::restore()` to restore a package from the global `renv` cache if available, thereby avoiding a retrieve + build + install of the package.

If it is not set, then `renv` will not use the cache and instead always try to retrieve the package from the declared source (which seems appropriate for your case).

Comment: Thank you! Can you confirm that following format is fine: `renv::record(nloptr@1.2.1)`